# mysql how to join a lot of row with one

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following tables:

**Player**

- id
- name

**Item**

- player_id
- item_id

How can I select all players from the Player table with all items from the Item table where Player.id=Item.player_id?

Do I need two queries? Or can a `JOIN` to cope with this?

Answer (score 1):

A simple join works.

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.ID, P.Name 
    FROM Player P
    INNER JOIN Item I on (I.player_id = P.id)
```

Comment: No. In that case, I'll get a lot of duplicate data about the player, if he has a lot of items.

Comment: It's normal? I think no

Comment: You just want distinct players?  Your question said you also wanted all items...  updated with `DISTINCT`.  You might clarify your question with an example of the output you actually want.

Comment: @YuriChechulin its natural dear, The Player Table is directly related to items ... So if 3 items are related to player ... the query will return 3 records of Player and corresponding items as well

Answer (score 0):

**Method 01-**  if you want just Items of a **Particular** player (Player =3)

> // 3 is not fix , it can b any number/Id of player

```
SELECT * FROM ITEM
WHERE PLAYER_ID = 3
```

**Method 02-** if you want to display Players with Items

```
SELECT * FROM PLAYER P
INNER JOIN ITEM I ON P.ID = I.PLAYER_ID
```

But as Chris Lively post. the multiple data of players w.r.t items is logical due to its relationship of parent child table :)